# Am I using rawgit wrong?

Tags: javascript, github

What am I doing wrong in this piece of code? When I use a local source for the theme it works correctly but it does not from github. I have looked through a lot of posts but cannot seem to find why this would not work, it is such simple code as well. The problem is in that second script with the theme but I do not know what, I also tried using it as "cdn.rawgit.com..." but that should not make any difference and it does not.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HighCharts Page</title>

        <!-- library (external) -->
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"> </script>
        <script src="https://rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/master/js/themes/grid-light.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script> $.getScript("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/highcharts/highcharts/master/js/themes/grid-light.js", function() {}); </script> -->
        <!-- end library (external) -->

        <!-- custom script (in-line JS) -->
        <script>

            //define a function here
            $(function () {
                var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'bar'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Fruit eaten'
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Jane',
                        data: [1, 0, 4]
                    }, {
                        name: 'John',
                        data: [5, 7, 3]
                    }]
                });
            });
        </script>
        <!-- end custom script (in-line JS) -->

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:500px;">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is probably something simple but thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you running this in an http or https site ? Because the problem might be with the first js file which you load through http so in an https site it would be blocked as mixed content.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I am just running this locally for testing for now. I literally just opened the file in my browser as is.

Comment: what OS/browser are you having the problem with ? because in Windows it works correct in latest Firefox/Chrome/IE

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I am using Chrome; I just updated it to check but still does not work. You are getting the right theme? Not just blue and black bars on a white background?

Comment: ok, now i get it.. i thought it was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that the file you use is the development version/source file which needs to be built in order to be functional (*in current browser versions*), as it imports other files (*and `import` is not yet supported by most browsers directly*).

Just use the CDN version at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/5.0.12/js/themes/grid-light.js

Comment: Thanks so much!! What do you mean by it needs to be built? I understand that import is not available yet but I am not sure I understand how this code goes around that. And also how did you find this?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 if you look at the src of the file you included you will see the `import` command that is not supported. If you go at the github repo you linked from you will see that it is the *working* repo as they mention (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts). I also just found by looking at their repos that they have a distribution repository (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-dist)  with the built version of their code, so you can use the theme from there https://rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts-dist/master/js/themes/grid-light.js

Comment: Ok, I see. So just to be clear, the working repo is for the development and not meant for regular users? And by built version, it means it's meant to run from a script?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 in this case yes, but each project has their own structure. I mean other projects have the distribution files in the same repository in a different folder.